# How to compare two Set collections in Java for unit tests?

Tags: java, junit

Is `assertTrue(SetUtils.equals(test1, test2), is(false));` (solution referred from https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-compare-two-sets/ where a SetUtils class is defined) 
the only correct approach for testing if two sets contains the same values or currently directly using `assertEquals(test1,test2);` is supported?

Comment: Have you tested it? Have you read the javadoc of assertEquals(). Of Set.equals()? If not, then do it. Beware: you might learn useful things.

Comment: True, did learn something useful. So assertEquals() internally calls the overridden equals() method for Set so the comparison for assertEquals() in case of Set with same values will return true. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same assertion in more elegant way using [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html). The reason is the unit tests are considered more as documentation for the code, so it is better to have more readable unit test. With assertj, you can do by:

> assertThat(test1).hasSameSizeAs(test2);

More examples [here](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-examples/blob/master/assertions-examples/src/test/java/org/assertj/examples/IterableAssertionsExamples.java)

Answer (score 0):

for comparing two java sets
you can use :

```
assertTrue(set1.containsAll(set2) && set2.containsAll(set1));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals` directly to compare 2 sets. Just pass in the 2 sets to be compared to it.

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

assertEquals(set1, set2); #usage
```